# Como es posible Que la función isPrime sepa que 11 es primo si en el for loop solo puede llegar hasta el 10

Tags: javascript

Como es posible que la función sepa que 11 es primo o no, si en el for loop i solo puede ser un número menos, es decir 10. ¿Como sabe que 11 es primo si nunca llega hasta el 11?

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
  // Helper function to check primality
  function isPrime(num) {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Check all numbers for primality
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i) == true)
      console.log(i);
  }

}
sumPrimes(10);
```

Comment: Yayo, amigo, el código debe ir en la pregunta y no como un enlace. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour] para que sepas cómo funciona [es.so]. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: No es necesario llegar al 11, es necesario llegar a la raiz cuadrada de 11.

Comment: Un numero primo solo tiene 2 factores, el `1` y si mismo. El loop revisa que luego del `1` y antes del numero no haya otro factor.

Comment: Si un numero n es un factor de num, eso significa que existe otro m que también es factor, ya que `n * m = num`. Vemos también que, a menos que n y m sean iguales (en cuyo caso ambos serían la raiz cuadrada de num), necesariamente uno de ellos es menor a la raiz cuadrada de num y el otro es mayor a esa raiz cuadrada. Por tanto, si hemos probado posibles factores sin encontrar ningún factor y hemos llegado a la raiz cuadrada de num, ya no hace falta seguir. No encontraremos tampoco nigún factor mayor. El número es primo.